# Stop NestedScrollView from scrolling to top when custom view is redrawn

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-nestedscrollview

I have a custom view inside a NestedScrollView. Every time invalidate is called on the view, the layout scrolls to top of the custom view. I want the scroll position to be unchanged after the view has been redrawn. Any idea how this can be done?

I have tried implementing an onScrollChangeListener and onGlobalLayoutListener in combination to rescroll to the previously scrolled position, but it doesn't work. I have the following code in the onCreateView method of a fragment.

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = layoutView.getViewTreeObserver();

if (scrollListener != null) {
        observer.removeOnScrollChangedListener(scrollListener);
    } else  {
        scrollListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                scrollX = layoutView.getScrollX();
                scrollY = layoutView.getScrollY();

            }
        };
    }

    observer.addOnScrollChangedListener(scrollListener);

    if (layoutListener != null) {
        observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener);
    } else {
        layoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (customView != null && scrollY != 0 && getUserVisibleHint()) {
                    layoutView.setVerticalScrollbarPosition(scrollY);
            }
        };
    }

    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener);
```

The following is the code for the onDraw and onMeasure method of the custom view.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (pieces == null) {
        return;
    }

    int position = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols && position < pieces.length; c++) {
            Paint paint = (pieces[position] ? complete : empty);

            int left = c * stepSize + borderSize + margin;
            int right = left + stepSize - borderSize * 2;
            int top = r * stepSize + borderSize;
            int bottom = top + stepSize - borderSize * 2;

            canvas.drawRect(left + borderSize, top + borderSize,
                    right + borderSize, bottom + borderSize, paint);

            ++position;
        }
    }

}



@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();

    cols = width / stepSize;

    rows = (int) Math.ceil((float) cells / (float) cols);
    margin = (width - cols * stepSize) / 2;

    int height = rows * stepSize;

    setMeasuredDimension(width, Math.max(width, height));


}
```

Comment: Invalidate implies only redrawing. No change in position or dimensions is happening to the view. So its position within the scroll view is unaffected. You don't need to jump any hoops to achieve this. If your view behaves unexpectedly, then its draw method is drawing wrong.

Comment: @EugenPechanec - I have added the code for the onDraw method of the custom view. Can you please tell if there's something wrong with it?